# What RBAC permissions needed for Argo Retry

Tags: permissions, kubernetes-pod, rbac, argoproj

I am hoping to be able to use the `argo retry my-wf` command in order to retry failed workflows. I thought the "create" permissions would suffice

```
    verbs:
      - create
```

but seems like this is not sufficient as i get an error about "doesn't have permission to delete pods", which I guess implies "retry" requires "delete". I hoped to find docs in the Argo project about the permissions needed for "retry" (https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/cli/argo_retry/) but couldn't find. Rather than guess and check does anyone know the "minimal" permissions needed?

Comment: did u solve? i have same issue

Comment: @tooptoop4 I wound up adding in the verb "delete" as well but haven't tested it or needed to use it in the past year. If you end up figuring it out please post as an answer